# Which is right: spaces and/or tabs in jquery?

Tags: jquery, syntax

I ran some jquery through jsLint, and it told me I should replace all the tabs with spaces. Is that right? And does mixing spaces and tabs matter?

Here's part of the code, if that helps (though my understanding is that stackoverflow converts all tabs to spaces):

```
function modal_dialog(share_div)
{
    $("#share_div_" + share_div).dialog({
        autoOpen: false,
        modal: true,
        height: 158,
        width: 400
    });

    $("#share_div_" + share_div).dialog("open");

    $(document).on("click", ".ui-widget-overlay", function() {
        $("#share_div_" + share_div).dialog("close");
    });
}
```

Comment: It doesn't matter to jQuery or Javascript. Beyond that, please don't reheat the age-old spaces vs. tabs wars. :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

jQuery is just a JavaScript library, so you're really asking whether your JavaScript code should use tabs or spaces.

The answer is it's really up to you. JSLint is a very opinionated program written by a very opinionated author. His opinions are worth listening to, but should not be taken as gospel - many experienced JavaScript developers have different opinions on some issues, even if they agree with him on others.

If you want a more flexible version of JSLint, try [JSHint](http://www.jshint.com/), a fork of JSLint with more options to customize it and less fussy about things that don't really matter.

Spaces and tabs in particular don't matter, as long as you're consistent in your code and indent things in a way that other developers can understand, and your code is easy to maintain. *Mixing* spaces and tabs is a bad idea; pick one or the other. At the very least, they should never be mixed in a given source file.

That's not to say that there aren't arguments to be made for spaces or for tabs. I prefer tabs myself and have good reasons for using them. Other people use spaces and have good reasons for using *them*. It just depends on which reasons are more important to each of us.

If you're editing someone else's file, see what indentation style they're using and stick with it. One thing I find very helpful is to use an editor like [Komodo](http://www.activestate.com/komodo-edit) which automatically detects the use of tabs or spaces and how much indentation is used if it's spaces, and sets its indentation settings to match each individual source file. That makes it easy to be consistent with a file I'm editing even if it doesn't follow my own personal conventions.

The way you're indenting your code looks fine, and the interesting thing about it is that either tabs or spaces would work equally well in your style. The one thing I would suggest changing is this:

```
function modal_dialog(share_div)
{
    // ...
}
```

Elsewhere you put the open curly brace on the same line instead:

```
$(document).on("click", ".ui-widget-overlay", function() {
    $("#share_div_" + share_div).dialog("close");
});
```

Like tabs vs. spaces, this is a case where it's best to be consistent. Pick one brace style or the other and use it everywhere.

In many languages, it wouldn't matter which way you write this. But in JavaScript putting the brace on the same line is a clear winner, because of this case:

```
function foo()
{
    return
    {
        a: 1,
        b: 2
    }
}
```

This turns out to be a syntax error because of automatic semicolon insertion. You *have* to put the curly brace on the same line as the `return` statement here. (Try it and see.) Since you have to do the `return` that way, you may as well do it that way everywhere:

```
function foo() {
    return {
        a: 1,
        b: 2
    }
}
```

Some coding styles do *not* work well with tabs, such as this way of writing long function calls that don't fit nicely on a single line:

```
    someFunctionWithLongName(firstParam,
                             secondParam + somethingAdded - subtracted,
                             thirdParam);
```

If you use tabs, then `secondParam` and `thirdParam` are going to line up with `firstParam` only if the tab settings are exactly right. This is one reason many people prefer spaces, or at least say "tabs for indentation, spaces for alignment". That is, use tabs up to the beginning of the `someFunctionWithLongName` call, and then spaces for the additional alignment after that for the second and third parameters.

I think this approach is a maintenance headache, and I prefer to just avoid the problem with a different formatting style:

```
    someFunctionWithLongName(
        firstParam,
        secondParam + somethingAdded - subtractThis,
        thirdParam
    );
```

Now once again it doesn't matter whether you choose tabs or spaces. The indentation will work out fine either way, and there's no column alignment where you have to worry about combining tabs and spaces.

Interestingly enough, this is also exactly how we indent code blocks:

```
    if( a ) {
        b();
        c();
    }
```

To me there's something very appealing in being able to treat {} and () the same regarding indentation. And yes, I also do [] the same way:

```
    var array = [
        firstElement,
        secondElement,
        thirdElement
    ];
```

Not:

```
    var array = [firstElement,
                 secondElement,
                 thirdElement];
```

Comment: Dude, *very* nice answer; but aren't you going a little off the rails with it? ;)

Comment: @deceze - Thanks! I guess going a little off the rails is in my blood... But I think I'm done for now! :-)

Comment: Very, very helpful answer! So (probably silly) follow-up for you: if I go with tabs, I don't have to use tabs between `function` and `foo()` for example and every other place with a space; it's just about indenting, correct?

Comment: That's right, and in fact this is something that just about everyone agrees on: If you use tabs, they are just for indentation and go only at the beginning of a line. Any other spacing within the line itself uses spaces.